# Access - Make a subform field no visible with a button on the parent form :)

Tags: ms-access, visible, subform

I have an access database with a parent form which has a subform in datasheet view. The subform has advanced fields that don't need to be visible all the time, lets go with one field "productcode" in subform "deliverylines", parent form is "deliveryheaders". So i need a button the main form that will make the "productcode" column visible.

This is what I've been trying but its just throwing errors at me :(

```
    Private Sub showadvanced_Click()
Me.DeliveryLines.Productcode.Visible = True
end sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to hide a column in datasheet view you would need to use code like the following:

`Forms(Me.Name)("deliverylines").Form.Controls("productcode").ColumnHidden = True`

This will set the column hidden property

Note the full syntax to refer to a control on a subform is as follows:

```
Forms("Your Form Name")("Subform Control Name").Form.Controls("Your Control Name")
```

The example code I have supplied presumes that your subform control name is deliverylines

Comment: Thank you very much! That works perfectly. Happy Christmas :)

Answer (score 1):

For a datasheet, you will need to set the column width to zero: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224081(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: Ace, thanks very much @remou. I was on the wrong track, that was just what I needed. Happy Christmas :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub showadvanced_Click()


If [DeliveryLines].Form![Productcode].ColumnWidth > 1 Then
[DeliveryLines].Form![Productcode].ColumnWidth = -2
Else
[DeliveryLines].Form![Productcode].ColumnWidth = 20
End If

End Sub
```